# how to find nearest grid points in the set of data points using matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, matlab-cvst, matlab-deployment

I have (x,y) points and how to find (x1,y1),(x1,y2),(x2,y1),(x2,y2) grid points in the set of data points(xi,yi)...

[image: grid points]

Comment: You are computing the points needed to perform bilinear interpolation.  Check the marked duplicate for more details on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `ceil` and `floor`.

They will round up and down a value, thus `ceil(3.2)` will output `4` and `floor(3.2)` will output `3`. The right combinations of ceil/floor `x` and `y` will give all the points you need.

Comment: thanks Ander Biguri but this is not work for all cases. bcoz of the reason is my all grid points are in decimal no. only. (like, x=[0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5],y=[1 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5], and i need [0.25,1.35]'s nearest grid points as [(0.2,1.3),(0.2,1.4),(0.3,1.3),(0.3,1.4)]

Comment: @kamal Multiply by ten you data........